# Paperclip giving wrong url. How to fix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, paperclip

My paperclip path in the model is:

```
has_attached_file :image, :path => ":rails_root/app/assets/images/article_images/:id/:style_:basename.:extension"
```

But when I call `article.image.url`, here is the url I get (which is broken):

```
/system/images/64294/original/fantastik.jpg?1324288670
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You also need to setup the URL, what you want is:

```
has_attached_file :image,
                   :path => ":rails_root/app/assets/images/article_images/:id/:style_:basename.:extension"
                   :url => "/app/assets/images/article_images/:id/:style_:basename.:extension"
```

The only thing I would question is if you're storing them in a good place. Typically, they would go in

```
/public/...
```

Or on another service like s3. However, that is how you modify the URL

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

like @andrewpthorp mention that's because you switch only path, but you can do it more DRY

paperclip defaults:

```
:url                   => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
:path                  => ":rails_root/public:url",
```

You can see that url can be part of path so your config should look like:

```
 has_attached_file :image,
   :url => "/app/assets/images/article_images/:id/:style_:basename.:extension",
   :path => ":rails_root:url"
```

Be carefull, usualy servers (apache, nginx) serves files only from public directory.

More options for `has_attached_file` you can find [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb)

Comment: It seems to me that the defaults have changed in recent versions. Used the ones shown here to fix a problem with my Rails app.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to fix the issue with :default_url:

```
:default_url => ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('empty-event-cover.png')
```